# What is the fastes batch_size for influxDBClient

Tags: python, influxdb, influxdb-python, batchsize

I want to write a list of 1,000,000 datapoints to my influxDB.
I use this command:

```
client.write_points(listOfPoints[:1000000], batch_size=1000000)
```

This returns Entity Error: InfluxDBClientError: 413: {"error":"Request Entity Too Large"}

Alternatively:

```
client.write_points(listOfPoints[:1000000], batch_size=100000)
```

This works perfectly fine.

How do I find the fastes batch_size?